# Can't use @BindingAdapter from remote gradle dependecies

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding, android-studio-3.0

I use [this library](https://github.com/drstranges/ActionHandler) to handle adapter action like this:

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:actionHandler="@{actionHandler}"
    app:actionType="@{ActionType.OPEN_URL}"
    app:actionTypeLongClick="@{ActionType.OPEN_DETAIL}"
    app:model="@{model}">
```

And then I got the build error:

```
 Error:(22, 30) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:actionHandler' 
 with parameter type com.drextended.actionhandler.listener.ActionClickListener 
 on android.widget.LinearLayout.
```

The convert (from @BindingAdapter) is already define in [Converters.java](https://github.com/drstranges/ActionHandler/blob/master/actionhandler/src/main/java/com/drextended/actionhandler/util/Converters.java)

**I also try with other remote dependencies but still not work.
The converters from other remote dependencies can't be used but my local modules's converters can**.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have shown. The default Binding Adapters use the same mechanism that dependant libraries use, so it is possible that either the dependency isn't set up properly or data binding isn't configured in the library.

Comment: @GeorgeMount I don't know. I can't use BindingAdapter from other remote dependencies (except my local modules).  If I copy class Converters.java above into my app, it can work well. Maybe it's related to android studio 3.0 issue?

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 may have an incompatibility with data binding libraries created prior to version 2.3. What version created the remote library?

Comment: @GeorgeMount The databinding is just enable by `dataBinding { enabled = true }` I don't know the version that you mentioned. But the gradle build tool of remote dependency is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1` and mine is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8`

Comment: That could be the problem. We recently discovered that compatibility with older versions has been broken in Android gradle plugin 3.0.